# How to test mapDispatchToProps with Jest & Enzyme?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following test coverage:

[image]

The fbLoginWithKeycloak action creator looks like this:

```
export const fbLoginWithKeycloak = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    const config = keyCloakService.fbLoginConfig()
    Login.start(config)
      .then(tokens => console.log('tokens'))
      .catch(e => { throw new Error('Error signing in!', e) })

    dispatch({ type: FB_LOGIN_WITH_KEYCLOAK })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd test `fbLoginWithKeycloak` in isolation and then reduce `mapActionToProps` to the bare-minimum by [providing an object instead of a function](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v4.4.9/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) so that dispatching props mapping doesn't need tests anymore.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fbLogin: fbLoginWithKeycloak,
};
```

If you wanted to go any further in the topic you'll find [this post](https://jsramblings.com/2018/01/15/3-ways-to-test-mapStateToProps-and-mapDispatchToProps.html) quite interesting.

Comment: but, how do I test the component `FacebookLogin` that calls this method `props.fbLogin` when clicked?